# Where to find datasheets for MOS (Commodore) 85xx chips?

Tags: commodore, chip, commodore-128, mos-650x

It seems difficult to find any detailed technical information online for the 85xx chips used in later Commodore 8-bit computers. For example, there's an excellent archive at http://www.6502.org/documents/datasheets/mos/ with datasheets for 65xx chips, but not the 85xx versions.

Is there some repository I've failed to locate that has the datasheets I need?

Comment: I’d suspect bitsavers has it tucked away somewhere, but haven’t time to check right now…

Comment: OK, bitsavers only has the 1982 MOS Technologies data book, which does not have 85xx chips.